# Plotting on log scale in VBA but have zero values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question and there might not be a good solution to it, but I might as well try.

I have plots where I need to use log scale to visualize the data correctly. However, since my limits (also plottet) can contain 0 values Excel errors me out, with good reason. Since the plots are only for the visual comparison I could just plot fx 0.000000001 instead of zero. Is there a way to add an If sentence to the below import code? The zero value will appear in the y-values.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "LSL"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$B$7:$F$7"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$B$9:$F$9"
```

I could transfer all data to a different sheet and transform the zero's and import from there, but I would very much like to avoid this.

Hope someone knows a solution.

Best Regards
Lonnie

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the range and edit the values before making the chart.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("B7:F7") ' change to your range
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        cell.Value = 0.0000001
    End If
Next cell


ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "LSL"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$B$7:$F$7"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$B$9:$F$9"
```

After the code is done this is the result.

[image]

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for your solution. The problem is that I am displaying the limits, so the limits depicted in the range need to be the actual ones, meaning zero. Can I do this without changing the values in the range?

Comment: @La82 so you need actual numbers in the table but "fake" in the chart? I don't think you can do that without a second table/sheet.

Comment: Yeah pretty much. No figured as much but I was hoping there was a way to store it as a range without plotting the values. I will just have to add another sheet.